# Inserting row alternatively in an excel sheet

Tags: excel, cell, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet which looks like this:

[image]

I want to insert row(or cell) below every filled cell. Like this: [image]

I have thousands of records so need to do this automatically. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-VBA approach would be to make a new sheet, and enter this formula in A1:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A, ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/2, 0))
```

Then select A1 and A2 (leaving A2 blank), copy it, select twice the number of rows as in Sheet1, and paste.

If you only want values, you could then select column A and copy, then paste special and paste values only.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in VBA with the following code:

```
Sub doIt()

    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim i As Long

    numRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    For i = numRows To 2 Step -1
        ActiveSheet.Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. select the raw that contains the data you want to separate by 1 cell at a time.
2. press F5.
3. click special.
4. at the Go to Special dialog box, click "Constant".
5. right click 1 of the selected cell and insert

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I found the following solution from https://www.pcmag.com/article/149833/insert-alternate-blank-rows-in-excel

You can create the blank rows separately and then interleave them with the existing rows by sorting. To start, insert a new column to the left of the existing column A. Enter 1 in cell A1 and highlight column A all the way to the last row that contains data. From the Edit menu select Fill | Series and click on OK. Column A should now contain numbers from 1 to the total number of rows. Press Ctrl-C to copy these cells to the clipboard, click in the cell just below the last of them, and press Ctrl-V to paste. Now highlight the entire data area, including the new rows with just a number in column A. Select Sort from the Data menu and choose the No header row option in the resulting dialog box. Under Sort by select Column A, under Then by select column B, and click on OK. Finally, delete column A. You now have a blank row after every one of the original 1,000-odd rows.

Because blank lines can often cause problems with charts or calculations, you may want a quick way to remove them. You can use a similar technique.

Again, insert a new column to the left of column A and fill a series from 1 to the end of the data. Highlight the entire data area and sort by column B (the first column of real data). This will group all of the blank rows together. Next, highlight the data area again, and re-sort by column A. The blank lines are gone, and your data is restored to its original order. Finally, remove column A.

Answer (score 0):

easy way:
in a free column (example is column A) fill the first 3 rows with 2,4,6
auto fill the column down to the end of your data.
At the end, fill the next 3 lines with 1,3,5
Autofill down the same amount of lines your data is
now select all, data-> sort-> A
wich will sort your data to 1, (empty) 2 (data) 3 () empty

;)